# excel vba / write formula to cell automatically adds @ to the formula string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to write a TRANSPOSE formula to a cell:

```
wsMyWorkSheets.Range(Cells(3 + vHeaderSize, 9), Cells(3 + vHeaderSize, 8 + vHeaderSize)).Value = "=TRANSPOSE(VaR)"
```

In excel however, I get '=@TRANSPOSE(@VaR)' which in turn returns a #VALUE error

Comment: 1. use `.Formula2` instead of `.Value` 2. what is `VaR`? is it a vba variable, a named range?

Comment: 3. the `Cells(...)` should also have the parent sheet assigned to them `wsMyWorkSheets.Cells(...)` or you will get an error when the active sheet is not `wsMyWorkSheets.`

Comment: VaR is just a range

Comment: A named range or a range variable in vba?

Comment: you may want to include more of your code and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: The answer is indeed the .Formula**2** (.Formula still gives the @). Also, to make it work I needed to write the formula to just the very 1st cell, as one does manually....